# There is no argument provided for parameter color_output with Boost.Test and CTest

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm getting this error on a recently created project using CTest and Boost 1.61.0 in OS X El Capitan.

This is my test's `CMakeLists.txt`, located in `core/tests/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Boost 1.32 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(EntryTest entry.spec.cpp)
target_link_libraries(EntryTest core ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})
add_test(EntryTest EntryTest)
```

And the actual dummy test, located in `core/tests/entry.spec.cpp`:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (EntryTest)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ShouldPass) {
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(1, 1);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

CTest reports:

```
$ cat Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log
Start testing: Aug 26 13:05 BOT
----------------------------------------------------------
1/1 Testing: EntryTest
1/1 Test: EntryTest
Command: "/Users/jviotti/Projects/timetrack/build/core/tests/EntryTest"
Directory: /Users/jviotti/Projects/timetrack/build/core/tests
"EntryTest" start time: Aug 26 13:05 BOT
Output:
----------------------------------------------------------
Test setup error: boost::runtime::access_to_missing_argument: There is no argument provided for parameter color_output
<end of output>
Test time =   0.01 sec
----------------------------------------------------------
Test Failed.
"EntryTest" end time: Aug 26 13:05 BOT
"EntryTest" time elapsed: 00:00:00
----------------------------------------------------------

End testing: Aug 26 13:05 BOT
```

I've tried tweaking `color_output` with both the `--color_output` option and the `BOOST_TEST_COLOR_OUTPUT` environment variable without luck ([see this documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/color_output.html)). The error persists despite any value I pass for such option.

The curious thing is that the test runs fine if I manually compile the test file, probably indicating a CMake configuration problem:

```
$ clang++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.61.0_1/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.61.0_1/include core/tests/entry.spec.cpp
$ ./a.out
Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you built with `VERBOSE=1`? Maybe this can help to identify differences.

Comment: Here's the verbose make output: http://pastebin.com/em0Gidbe. I can't seem to be able to stop anything interesting there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve the `missing_argument` problem by using the dynamic linking variant of the Unit Test Framework, like so:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_unit_tests
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

Instead of the single-header variant, which you use:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

The rest of the code and CMake script remains exactly the same.